# How to stop dhcp logging to /var/log/syslog and messages?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, dhcp, logfiles

I have installed `isc-dhcp` on Jessie. It works.
However, I noticed it logs to three log files in `/var/log/`:

1. `syslog`
2. `messages`
3. `dhcp.log`

I'd like to keep dhcpd to log to `dhcp.log` and stop it from logging to `syslog` and `messages`.

I have this line in `dhcpd.conf`:

```
log-facility local7;
```

I have added the following to `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
local7.*        /var/log/dhcp.log
```

And also added the second line below.

```
\*.=info;\*.=notice;*.=warn;\  
    /dhcpd,local7.none;/\  
    auth,authpriv.none;\  
    cron,daemon.none;\  
    mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages
```

I restarted `dhcp` and `syslog`, still the same; `dhcp` logs to all three log files.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

You can do this without editing your config files by using symbolic links.

First delete the log file you don't want to keep :

```
rm /var/log/syslog  
rm /var/log/messages
```

Next create a symbolic link that lead to /dev/null :

```
ln -s /dev/null /var/log/syslog
ln -s /dev/null /var/log/messages
```

Now DHCP will still write informations on these "files", but the content will be live deleted :)

Edit : If anyone knows how to do this in the config file, it would be nice !

Comment: Well, I want to kepp syslog and messages; but do not want dhcp to log to it.

Comment: Disabling system logs is a terrible advice, -1.

Comment: I agree with this ! Any better answer is welcomed :)